# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: Saving Dom tree

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I am using **PHP** code to parse a website using **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser** and then save multiple **div's** in a **htm** file. The problem I am having is saving the **DOM Tree**.  As of the moment the it is being saved using **FILE_PUT_CONTENTS** and has to use **FILE_APPEND** so that the **div's** wont over write each other. But this is a problem as each time the **PHP** code is run it adds more to the file which I don't want. I looked at a few options but couldn't make sense of it. I hope you can help me and thank you for your time.

Below is my current **PHP** code

```
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div) 
{
file_put_contents('site/test.htm', $div, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Below is my **HTML** code with edited **PHP**

```
<?php
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
$divContents = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div)
{
$divContents[] = $div->outertext;
}
file_put_contents('site/test.htm', implode(PHP_EOL, $divContents));
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#wrap').load('site/test.htm');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
</body>
```

Below is the link for **test.htm**

http://roosterteeth.t15.org/site/test.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd still use `->outertext`, but simply save the content to an array, and then you can use `file_put_contents` on the imploded array, and hence overwrite the file with *all* of the divs:

```
<?php
    include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');

    $divContents = array();

    foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div) 
    {
        $divContents[] = $div->outertext;
    }

    file_put_contents('site/test.htm', implode(PHP_EOL, $divContents));
?>
```

Comment: I have one last question I would like to ask. When the file is saved it puts each div inside each other. So the second div will be inside the first and so on. is there a way to make them separate?

Comment: @Sabre That doesn't really make sense - this should place them beside eachother - on individual lines. What's the actual source of the file (if you open up the HTML file with a text editor)? Can you post this to OP?